How to consistently trigger "onPaste" event in EditText for phone number validation and formatting?
I am working on an Android application where I need to validate and format phone numbers when pasted into an EditText. Here's what I have so far:
The first time I paste a phone number, the onPaste event is triggered as expected, and the validation/formatting works perfectly.
However, if I delete all the characters and paste again, the behavior seems to switch to the onInput event instead of onPaste, which breaks the desired functionality.
I would like the paste operation to always trigger the onPaste event regardless of the state of the EditText.
I have tried the following things

Implemented a TextWatcher to monitor changes in the EditText.
Overridden onTextChanged to handle formatting when input changes.
Tried using a ClipboardManager to detect paste events.

class AccountNumberWatcher(
    private val editText: EditText,
    private val onInvalidPhoneNumber: (() -> Unit)? = null
) : TextWatcher {

    private var isUpdating = false
    private var isPasteAction = false
    private val MAX_LENGTH_SHORT = 12
    private val MAX_LENGTH_LONG = 15

    init {
        editText.setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
            if (event.action == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                isPasteAction = isPasteDetected()
            }
            false
        }
    }

    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}

    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
        if (isUpdating) return

        val originalText = s?.toString() ?: return

        // If it's a paste action, we handle it differently
        if (isPasteAction) {
            handlePasteAction(originalText)
        } else {
            handleInputAction(originalText)
        }

        // Reset the paste action flag
        isPasteAction = false
    }

    private fun handlePasteAction(originalText: String) {
        val formattedNumber = AppUtils.formatMobileNo(originalText)
        val maxLength = if (formattedNumber.length > MAX_LENGTH_SHORT) MAX_LENGTH_LONG else MAX_LENGTH_SHORT
        editText.filters = arrayOf(InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength))

        if (formattedNumber != originalText) {
            isUpdating = true
            editText.setText(formattedNumber)
            editText.setSelection(formattedNumber.length)
            isUpdating = false
        }

        if (formattedNumber.length > MAX_LENGTH_SHORT) {
            onInvalidPhoneNumber?.invoke()
        }
    }

    private fun handleInputAction(originalText: String) {
        val formattedNumber = AppUtils.formatMobileNo(originalText)
        val maxLength = if (formattedNumber.length > MAX_LENGTH_SHORT) MAX_LENGTH_LONG else MAX_LENGTH_SHORT
        editText.filters = arrayOf(InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength))

        if (formattedNumber != originalText) {
            isUpdating = true
            editText.setText(formattedNumber)
            editText.setSelection(formattedNumber.length)
            isUpdating = false
        }

        if (formattedNumber.length > MAX_LENGTH_SHORT) {
            onInvalidPhoneNumber?.invoke()
        }
    }

    // Check if the clipboard contains text, indicating a paste action
    private fun isPasteDetected(): Boolean {
        val clipboard = editText.context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
        return clipboard.hasPrimaryClip() && clipboard.primaryClip?.getItemAt(0)?.text != null
    }
}


//in fragment 
binding.etContactSearch.addTextChangedListener(
            PhoneNumberWatcher(binding.etContactSearch){
                AppUtils.showSnackBar(binding.root, getString(R.string.message_error_phone_number))
            }
        )

How can I ensure that pasting a phone number into the EditText always triggers the onPaste event, even after clearing the field? Are there any best practices for handling consistent paste event detection and phone number formatting in this case?
Any insights or code samples would be greatly appreciated.

How are you listening for the onPaste event? Adding that code here may be helpful. You can also clean up your question by removing your specific formatting/validation logic.
